# Stop Arduino Timer after some seconds

Tags: timers, arduino-yun, buzzer

I'm building a basic program that when a button is pressed, a buzzer comes on.

I would like however to make it so that the buzzer stops after a short period of time (e.g. 5-7 seconds).

Here is the code I have so far which is pretty basic I know forgive me but I have no clue on how to go forward.

```
// Setting The Pin Numbers
const int touchsensor = 2;     // the number of the touchsensor pin
const int buzzer =  4;         // the number of the LED pin

// variables:
int touchsensorState = 0;      // variable for reading the touchsensor status

void setup() {
  // initialize the buzzer as an output:
  pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
  // initialize the touchsensor as an input:
  pinMode(touchsensor, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // read state of the pushbutton value:
  touchsensorState = digitalRead(touchsensor);

  // check if the touch sensor is pressed. If it is, the touchsensorState is HIGH:
  if (touchsensorState == HIGH) {
    // buzzer will emit sound:
    digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
  } else {
    // buzzer will not sound:
    digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
  }
}
```

Comment: Easy way: After turning on the buzzer, `delay` for your wanted amount of milliseconds, then turn the buzzer off. Little bit harder but more efficient way: Blink without Delay technique (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set a `timestamp = millis()` when the button is pushed and then you disable the buzzer only when `millis() - timestamp > timeout`

```
if (touchsensorState == HIGH) {
    // buzzer will emit sound:
    digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
    timestamp = millis();
} 
if(millis() - timestamp > timeout) {
    // buzzer will not sound:
    digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
}
```

Comment: Note: If you press the button during the time the buzzer is active, it will re-write the timestamp so that it is triggered in "now + timestamp", i.e. prolong the time when it's turned off. You may want to insert a "if button is already active, do not modify timestamp" logic if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can time this with the `millis()` function. Refer to the BlinkWithoutDelay example from the Arduino IDE.

Then you set a timestamp, when the button is pressed:

```c
if(touchsensorState == HIGH) timestamp = millis();
```

And then you are checking this timestamp against the current time:

```c
if(millis() - timestamp > duration){
  digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
} else {
  digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
}
```

`duration` is the timespan during which the buzzer should stay on after the button was released. If you want to turn it of, regardless of the button state, you can add a boolean flag to your if-statement, to set the timestamp only, when the button was pressed first:

```c
if(!button_pressed && touchsensorState == HIGH){
  timestamp = millis();
  button_pressed = true;
}
```

In this case you have to reset the `button_pressed` variable to `false`, when you are turning of the buzzer in the `millis()`-else-statement

Comment: I keep getting timestamp was not declared in this scope?

Comment: because you have to declare it as a variable (of type unsigned long, since this is the return type of millis())